# Reading XML in SQL Server of the specified XML node's "name" and get its "value"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I read the following XML in a SQL Server database:

```
<Row>
    <Keys>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_2</Name>
        <Data>22</Data>
      </Key>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_3</Name>
        <Data>33</Data>
      </Key>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_1</Name>
        <Data>98</Data>
      </Key>
    </Keys>
</Row>
```

I want to select from that XML and get only one row with columns:

```
NAME_1, NAME_2, NAME_3.
```

That's why I need something which would let me to find Keys/Key/Name with the value: NAME_1 and return its Keys/Key/Data, and so on ...

Expected resultset (1 ROW):

```
NAME_1  NAME_2  NAME_3
-----------------------
   98     22      33
```

One more important thing. Those values NAME_1, NAME_2, NAME_3. I am expecting them. That's why I need to query for them and return their values for a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my approach with expected names:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Row>
    <Keys>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_2</Name>
        <Data>22</Data>
      </Key>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_3</Name>
        <Data>33</Data>
      </Key>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_1</Name>
        <Data>98</Data>
      </Key>
    </Keys>
</Row>';
```

--Most explicit (recommended) version:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Row/Keys/Key[(Name/text())[1]="NAME_1"]/Data/text())[1]','int') AS NAME_1
      ,@xml.value('(/Row/Keys/Key[(Name/text())[1]="NAME_1"]/Data/text())[1]','int') AS NAME_1
      ,@xml.value('(/Row/Keys/Key[(Name/text())[1]="NAME_2"]/Data/text())[1]','int') AS NAME_2;
```

--The same, but less explicit (and therefore not recommended)

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//Key[Name="NAME_1"]/Data)[1]','int') AS NAME_1
      ,@xml.value('(//Key[Name="NAME_2"]/Data)[1]','int') AS NAME_1
      ,@xml.value('(//Key[Name="NAME_3"]/Data)[1]','int') AS NAME_2;
```

The idea in short:

- we fetch each value directly from the XML
- We pick the `<Key>` with a XQuery-predicate asking for the element, where `<Name>` as the given string as content (= `text()` node).
- We dive into the `<Data>` node *below* the `<Key>` and fetch its content and return it as `int`.

Comment: What is it all about "explicit" here? Why the first has an advantage over second? Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @John, with a small and clean xml there's no measurable difference. But with large xmls there might be a Name-element in various places. Furthermore, the explicit call is the fastest in most cases. The more the engine knows in advance the better...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the column names will *always* be `NAME_1`, `NAME_2`, `NAME_3`, etc, you can do the following without having to resort to dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @xml xml =
'<Row>
    <Keys>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_2</Name>
        <Data>22</Data>
      </Key>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_3</Name>
        <Data>33</Data>
      </Key>
      <Key>
        <Name>NAME_1</Name>
        <Data>98</Data>
      </Key>
    </Keys>
</Row>';

SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
         x.f.value( 'Data[1]', 'int' ) AS [Data],
         x.f.value( 'Name[1]', 'varchar(50)' ) AS [Name]
    FROM @xml.nodes( '//Row/Keys/Key' ) x( f )
) AS d
PIVOT (
    MAX( [Data] )
    FOR [Name] IN ( [NAME_1], [NAME_2], [NAME_3] )
) AS x;
```

Returns

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| NAME_1 | NAME_2 | NAME_3 |
+--------+--------+--------+
|     98 |     22 |     33 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```